# Subtraction of Big O notation

Tags: convergence-divergence

Imagine that I have:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n O(n^{-1/2}) - \sum_{i = 1}^n O(n^{-1/2}).$$

By rewriting in the following way we could have

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n O(n^{-1/2}) - \sum_{i = 1}^n O(n^{-1/2}) = \sum_{i = 1}^n O(1)n^{-1/2} - \sum_{i = 1}^n O(1)n^{-1/2} = O(1) [\sum_{i = 1}^n n^{-1/2} - \sum_{i = 1}^n n^{-1/2}] = O(1) \sum_{i = 1}^n (n^{-1/2} - n^{-1/2}) = O(1) \cdot 0 = 0$$

However, by following many text books

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n O(n^{-1/2}) - \sum_{i = 1}^n O(n^{-1/2}) = O(\sqrt{n}) \neq 0$$

Therefore I am wondering **which step** in my development is wrong. Which one I am not allowed to do?

Comment: $\sum_{i = 1}^n O(1)n^{-1/2} - \sum_{i = 1}^n O(1)n^{-1/2} = O(1) [\sum_{i = 1}^n n^{-1/2} - \sum_{i = 1}^n n^{-1/2}]$ is wrong - $O(1)$ is not a single number

Comment: Think about set $O(f)-O(f)$, does it contain it only $0$ function?